# How can I solve the error to open google chrome on the server?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, digital-ocean

I have run the command google-chrome on the server and I have got this error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEjAr.png

When I tried this solution.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/spaVI.png
and I have got this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VxcP.png

Answer (score 1):

You must not run any application as `root` unless it requires `root` privileges. Chrome does not require `root` privileges.

Chrome has protections that prevent it running with `root` privileges, and the errors you are seeing are caused by those.

In order to run Chrome properly, you need to create a normal user account and log in using that user account. Remember to set up a strong passphrase for the new user.